# Open file with multiple spaces and save as array/data frame with two variables

Tags: python

I have a text file of the form:

```
data=
11  Open Water
12  Perennial Ice/Snow
21  Developed, Open Space   
22  Developed, Low Intensity    
23  Developed, Medium Intensity
112 Developed, High Intensity
113 Barren Land
0   No data
```

I want to read the file and save it as an array or data frame (column names = Code, Name) and be able to access the columns as data['Code'] or data['Name'].

print(data) command would generate:

```
Code      Name
11        Open Water
12        Perennial Ice/Snow
21        Developed, Open Space 
22        Developed, Low Intensity  
23        Developed, Medium Intensity
112       Developed, High Intensity
113       Barren Land
0         No data
```

My code as of now:

```
myfile = open("filename.txt",'r')
for line in myfile:
    Code, Name = line.split(' ', 1)
    data=Code + " " + Name
    print(data)
```

But this is wrong as each line in **data** is a bunch of strings, and not two strings. How should I open this file as two variables?

Comment: is 'Code' the line number?

Comment: No. 'Code' is the name of the variable, or the head of the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data=Code + " " + Name
```

The above line merges the contents of the two variables `Code` and `Name` into a single string variable.

You can declare an empty list, and append to it as you iterate through the file.

```
mydata = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # remember to remove trailing newline characters.
        code, name = line.strip('\n').split(' ', 1)
        mydata.append((code, name))
```

Then the resulting list `mydata` will contain *rows* with *two columns* each. (its a list of two-element-tuples)

The first column in each row will be `code`, and the second `name`. However, at this stage, `code` is still a string. to convert it to an int (which I assume you want to do), replace

```
mydata.append((code, name))
```

with

```
mydata.append((int(code), name))
```

Finally, to read the data into a data frame, you can simply pass `mydata` as

```
mydata_df = pandas.DataFrame(mydata)
```

Once in the data frame, you can change the column names to suit your uses.

```
mydata_df.columns = ['Code', 'Name']
```

Then, you'll be able to access the individual columns by their column names, e.g. `mydata_df['Code']` or `mydata_df.Code`.

Comment: Thank you! I added ".replace("\n", "")" to the end of name here: mydata.append((int(code), name.replace("\n", ""))) to remove the spaces at the end of the strings. I also added "mydata_df.columns = ['Code', 'Names']" to have the column names. It works well!

Comment: Glad it worked out. yes, I forgot to strip the terminating newline character. updating answer now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are dealing with a fixed width file and it seems you'd like to use pandas based on the syntax of  your referencing the data. Here's a start.

The first section takes the length (number of lines) in your text file and creates a DataFrame with two columns (Code, Name), and with the length of the text file.

The second section loops through each of those lines and assigns the first 4 characters to the first column 'Code', and the last few characters (except the new line character) into the second column 'Name'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "path to your file"
length = len(open(path).readlines())
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Code','Name'], index = np.arange(length))


sample = open(path)
lines = sample.readlines()
for i, j in enumerate(lines):
    df.loc[i,'Code'] = j[0:3]
    df.loc[i,'Name'] = j[4:].replace("\n", "")
print df
print df['Code']
print df['Name']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the codes are unique you can build a dictionary where the code is the key and the string is the value:

*data.txt*

```
11  Open Water
12  Perennial Ice/Snow
21  Developed, Open Space   
22  Developed, Low Intensity    
23  Developed, Medium Intensity
112 Developed, High Intensity
113 Barren Land
0   No data
```

*code (python 2.7)*

```
data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    data[int(line.split()[0])] = ' '.join(line.split()[1:])

#what you can do now

print data[22] #Developed, Low Intensity
print data[112] #Developed, High Intensity
print sorted(data.keys()) #[0, 11, 12, 21, 22, 23, 112, 113]
print data.values() #['No data', 'Open Water', 'Perennial Ice/Snow', 'Developed, High Intensity', 'Barren Land', 'Developed, Open Space', 'Developed, Low Intensity', 'Developed, Medium Intensity']
print data # {0: 'No data', 11: 'Open Water', 12: 'Perennial Ice/Snow', 112: 'Developed, High Intensity', 113: 'Barren Land', 21: 'Developed, Open Space', 22: 'Developed, Low Intensity', 23: 'Developed, Medium Intensity'}
```

Comment: This looks good. However, the result is a list of strings. I want when I type data[Code] or data[Name] to get the result as a column.

Comment: If you would like to print each value on a newline you can simply do `for i in data.values(): print i` and similar for the codes `for j in sorted(data.keys()): print j`.